# Form Validation with valid and invalid class

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a large form with form validations and I want to do validation on user input like async. I have done with validation for one field what I want but if I have several fields I do not know how to validate individual fields.

Here is sample code for what I have tried:

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <p>
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" (blur)="validcls()" (keyup)="validcls()" [class.valid]="validclass" [class.invalid]="invalidclass">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="password">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </form>

validcls(){
    if (this.form.controls.firstname.valid){
      this.validclass = true;
      this.invalidclass = false;
    }
    else if (this.form.controls.firstname.invalid || 
      this.form.controls.firstname.touched){
      this.validclass = false;
      this.invalidclass = true;
    }
  }
```

You can see full working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfz58j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[class.valid]="this.form.controls.firstname.valid"
```

and

```
[class.invalid]="this.form.controls.firstname.touched && this.form.controls.firstname.invalid"
```

That's it. Change the control name for each input. Note that I modified the second condition, because I believe that this is the behaviour you would want. Of course, if that is not the case, you could modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it by using ngClass no need of keyup function.

**html**

```
<section class="sample-app-content">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <p>
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" 
            [ngClass]="{'valid':form.get('firstname').valid,
            'invalid':form.get('firstname').invalid}">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="{'valid':form.get('password').valid,
            'invalid':form.get('password').invalid}">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</section>
```

demo stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9t56r?file=app%2Fapp.component.html